# GD Lib - Text with background over image

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

This one is quite difficult to explain clearly. So I think pictures might help.

I currently have a script that adds some text over an image in a custom font. I now want make it so that the text has a rectangular background to sit on.

The code I currently have is:

```
        $rImg = ImageCreateFromJPEG($_REQUEST['imageurl']);
        $cor = imagecolorallocate($rImg, 255, 255, 255);
        $font = 'font.TTF';
        imagettftext($rImg, 34, 0, 0, 100, $cor, $font, urldecode('Test Text'));
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($rImg,NULL,100);
```

It creates an image like this:

[image]

I need the image to look something like this:

[image]

Does anyone know a simple way of achieving this look? The red rectangle needs to end within range of the image. I would just use CSS, but it's for email!

Appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should calculate the boundaries of the text, so you can know how big red box you need. You could achive this with [imagettfbbox](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) function. Once you know the dimensions you can draw rectangle using [imagefilledrectangle](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledrectangle.php) function. Also you should draw rectangle before you draw text.

Comment: Great thanks - After a small amount of fiddling it's looking great!